# Error while starting apache Undefined symbol dlopen in libapr-1.so.0

Tags: linux, apache, apr

I have downloaded apache source code (2.4.9) and also downloaded apr and apr-util and kept in srclib directory under httpd-2.4.9 folder.
I configured and compiled apache with options: --prefix=/usr/apache --enable-mods-shared=all --with-ssl={ssl directory} --enable-deflate --with-z={z lib directory} --with-included-apr 
The platform i am usingLis RHEL 6.
This installed apache works fine on this machine.

But when I copy this apache folder on another linux machine (SUSE 11). It give me following error while starting apache
error while loading libapr-1.so.0 : Undefined symbol dlopen.

Can you please help me to identify what is going wrong here.

Comment: You should read the following for an explanation: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html

Basically the program you compiled on RHEL 6 is looking for a file which does not exist in the search path on your other machine. I would recommend setting the rpath to a relative path using $ORIGIN in this situation and put the lib somewhere relative to your custom apache binary

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. How to identify which file it is trying to find and not able to find on suse linux

Comment: .The stadard tool for this is `ldd` (mentioned in the link)

Comment: But when I do ldd with libapr-1.so.0 I dont any library which is missing

Comment: Are you using the libapr-1.so.0 which you built yourself or are you using the one provided by SUSE. If I compile packages myself then personally I like to make sure I am using the libraries I built myself to avoid any unexpected surprises

Comment: Yes I built libapr by my own on rhel and using the same on suse. In fact it  also shows in error the same path of libapr which is path of my built library

Comment: Post the output of ldd as it appears when you run it from both systems (the one where it works and the one where it doesn't work) into your question and maybe someone can say more.